# Scraperwiki Twitter Query

Tags: twitter, scraperwiki

Please forgive me, as I have limited knowledge of scraperwiki and twitter mining.

I have the following code to scrape twitter data. However, I want to edit the code to only give me results that are geotagged for New York on a particular date (let's say, April 1, 2013). Do you know how I should do this?

```
###############################################################################
# Twitter srcaper for the term 'hello'.
###############################################################################

import scraperwiki
import simplejson

# retrieve a page
base_url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='
q = 'hello'
options = '&rpp=10&page='
page = 1

while 1:
    try:
        url = base_url + q + options + str(page)
        html = scraperwiki.scrape(url)
        #print html
        soup = simplejson.loads(html)
        for result in soup['results']:
            data = {}
            data['id'] = result['id']
            data['text'] = result['text']
            data['from_user'] = result['from_user']
            data['created_at'] = result['created_at']
            # save records to the datastore
            scraperwiki.datastore.save(["id"], data)
        page = page + 1
    except:
        print str(page) + ' pages scraped'
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to `q`, use the query parameters `geocode` and `until`. See this page of the  [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets). Please note that you cannot use the Search API to find Tweets older than [about a week](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).

Besides, it's easier to use `urllib.urlencode()` to construct your query, like for example

```
query_dict = {'q':'search term(s)', 'geocode':'37.781157,-122.398720,25mi', 'until':'2013-05-10'}
query = urllib.urlencode(query_dict)
response = urllib.urlopen(basic_url + query).read()
```

**Update:** Please see [this example scraper](https://scraperwiki.com/scrapers/basic_twitter_scraper_533/) that you can copy and adapt to your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm so appreciative of your help. If it's not too much of a hassle, I would like to clarify one thing. I want to be able to feed this output into ArcGIS - with the geocode coordinates. Is there a way I can tweak this result with a printout of the coordinates?         for result in result_json['results']:
            #print result
            scraperwiki.sqlite.save(unique_keys=['id'], data=result, table_name="Tweets")

Comment: You can add the coordinates you searched for just before you put the date into the SQLite table: `result['geocode'] = geocode` I've adjusted the scraper accordingly.

Comment: So incredibly helpful. Thank you!!